# Передача Apache HttpClient из одного класса в другой(со всем прилагающим)

Tags: apache, android, java, классы, httpclient

Имеется два разных класса(два разных файла с классами) 
1 - Login.java(class)
2 - Main.java(class)

В классе Login я хочу авторизоваться на сайте посредством передачи POST запроса, затем в классе Main авторизованным ходить по *сайту*

Как происходит авторизация :

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost LoginON = new HttpPost("http://www.site.ru/login.php");
            List <NameValuePair> login = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "login"));
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "passwd"));

            LoginON.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(login, HTTP.UTF_8));

            ResponseHandler<String> LoginHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String LoginBody = httpclient.execute(LoginON, LoginHandler);
```

**Вопрос.** Как мне передать httpclient из Login в Main класс?

Comment: у вас это уже второй подобный вопрос, поэтому рекомендую вам поучить азы программирования на Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь вопрос упирается не в HttpClient, а в то как передать из одного класса в другой класс некий объект. В Java это можно сделать 2-мя способами:

а) Сохранить значение объекта в
        члене какого-нибудь класса и по мере
        необходимости брать его геттером.
        Применительно к Android это можно
        реализовать в виде приватного члена
        класса Application или тупо
        забабахать его в виде статического
        глобального члена 
 б) Второй способ передать объект в качестве
    параметра при вызове какого-либо метода/функции

В Android есть еще одно средство - передача объекта в качестве `Parcel` - посылки, правда объект должен для этого реализовать интерфейс Parcelable или иметь примитивный тип.

Я лично предпочитаю пользоваться методом а) - хотя в качестве быстрого хотфикса метод б) тоже потянет.

Comment: А можно с примерами? =)

Comment: Ты что офигел что ли... может еще ключ показать от квартиры где бабки лежат? Малька головой то поработай...

Comment: Я не офигел, уважаемый, а лишь попросил пару простеньких примеров, если это так сложно то ответить можно в более спокойной манере. И нет, ключи от *квартиры где бабки лежат* мне не нужны, но спасибо за предложение.

Comment: Kenpachi - без обид - но достаточно погуглить по ключевым словам из ответа Бармалея и примеров нашлось достаточно чтоб понять направление...

Comment: Мне как кодящему на Яве 6 дней, не очень понятно что он хочет до меня донести.